# How to remove redundant exchanges in Spark DAG

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I've two medium sized tables (tableA and tableB) where I'm joining tableB twice with tableA on the same join key.

```
...
from tableA A
left join tableB B1 on A.col1 = B1.col1
left join tableB B2 on A.col2 = B2.col1
```

I'm seeing that tableB is getting exchanged twice in the spark DAG.
[image: SparkDAG]

Since, the exchange is happening on the same join key (col1), I was curious on whether the 2nd exchange can be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in principle this is possible and there are two techniques you can consider:

1. caching - you can repartition the table B and then cache it and use this cached table in your joins. That will make sure that it will be shuffled only once. It is however not very suitable for large tables that will not fit in the memory.
2. reused exchange - if the Exchanges are identical, Spark will reuse the `Exchange` automatically. In your case, I can see from the plan that they are not identical because the second `Exchange` is showing more data (419MB in the second `Exchange` vs 325MB in the first `Exchange`). This might be caused for example by different projection (maybe you select different columns in each case later on and the `columnPruning` rule will prune the columns). If you can make sure that both Exchanges are identical (the sub-branch that is before the `Exchange` operator has the same operators with the same expressions as the second `Exchange` sub-branch) Spark will reuse it and you will see in the plan the `ReusedExchange` operator.

You may check my recent [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/be-in-charge-of-query-execution-in-spark-sql-c83d1e16b9b8) about the technique of reusing the `Exchange`.

Comment: Great answer! As you mentioned caching won't be a favorable option for me. As for your 2nd point, I'm not really sure how the 2 exchanges have data difference as I'm joining the entire table in both the joins as you can see from the toy code.

Comment: Can you please provide the entire query that produced the plan? What comes after the joins?

Comment: After this its a simple collect op to show at console.